# SQL Assertion/Trigger: how to set an attribute to forbid decreasing updates

Tags: sql, triggers, assertion

I have a table called person, one of the attributes is years_worked.

I need to find a way to restrict years_worked from being decreased, so that
a trigger/assertion (not sure what to use here) will only allow increases on updates.

Comment: @pltm_dev I don't think you understood Martin's question.  Which database engine do you need this written for??

Comment: I have understood it, no particular engine yet, any abstract answer (such as yours) is good for me

Comment: There isn't really a "standard" answer. A SQL Server answer will probably look nothing like one for Oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code will just revert all `years_worked` updated values that don't fall into your restriction back to what they were before the update.  This is for **SQL Server**, I can't speak for other RDBMS'.

```
create trigger RestrictYearsWorked
on person
after update
as

    update person
    set years_worked = d.years_worked
    from person p
    inner join deleted d
    on p.yourIdCol = d.yourIdCol
    where p.years_worked < d.years_worked

go
```